# I am trying to use tapply() for dataframe in R.Getting an error when referencing using index

Tags: r, tapply

```
a<-c(1,2,3)
b<-c("apple","orange","fruits")
f<-c(10,12,30)
df<-data.frame(a,b,f)
```

When I run :

```
prices<-tapply(df[1]*df[3],df[2],cumsum)
```

I get this error:

```
#Error in tapply(df[1] * df[3], df[2], cumsum) : 
#  arguments must have same length
```

However, if I use:

```
tapply(a*f,b,cumsum)
```

I get the output:

```
#apple fruits orange 
#   10     90     24
```

What is the difference? Why is this happening?

Comment: You are not referencing the columns properly, it should be `df[, 3] * df[, 4], df[, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

`tapply` expects in general to receive two vector arguments and the function, but by using single square brackets to subset you've given it two lists.  The second (`INDEX`) gets converted from a list (length 1) to a factor (length 3) internally so is then a different length to the first (`X`).  Unlisting is one option, though as @emilliman5 pointed out it is better to reference the column of the data table.

```
> tapply(unlist(df[1]*df[3]),df[2],cumsum)
b
 apple fruits orange 
    10     90     24 
> tapply(df[,1]*df[,3],df[,2],cumsum)
 apple fruits orange 
    10     90     24
```